# Find all possible n pairs without repetitions in a list of length 2n?

Tags: python, combinatorics

Given a list of size 2n, how to find all possible n pairs without repetitions? The algorithm is better to be optimal since n is large in my case.

E.g. giving a list

```
[1, 2, 3, 4],
```

it should return

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[1, 3], [2, 4]]
[[1, 4], [2, 3]]
```

In general, it should return (2n, 2) * *(2n-2, 2)* * ... * (2, 2) 2D lists, where (n, m) is the combinatorial number that picks m items within n items.

I am using Python 3. I tried Python *itertools.combinations* to solve this in brute-force way in 3 steps:

1. Find all ordered-pairs [i, j], i<j, e.g. in the above examples, we have
   [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4].
2. Using itertools.combinations to combine the above pairs into n pairs, e.g. it has
   [[1, 2], [1, 3]], etc
3. Remove pairs in step 2 with repetitions by flattening them into 1D and then using Python set and then comparing the length, i.e. [[1, 2], [1, 3]] is bad since 1 is repeated. The set that this list corresponds to is {1,2,3} which has length 3 but not 4. So, it is removed.

**I aim to speed-up the algorithm rather than using the above brute-force method since n is large in my case.**

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your calculation for the number of combinations is wrong, as shown by your simple example.  choose(4, 2) * choose(2, 2) = 6 * 1 = 6, yet as you see, there are only three possibilities.  You do not want the algorithm to produce both `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` and `[[3, 4], [1, 2]` but consider these to be the same result.  You need to take your calculation and divide by n!

That said.  Look at all the results in "canonical" representation, as you have above

```
[[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3], .....]
```

The canonical representation is
where `x1 < x2 < x3 < ....`, `x1 < y1`, `x2 < y2`, `x3 < y3`, ....

From this, it is easy to see that `x1` must be 1, `x2` must be the smallest of all elements after removing `x1` and `y1`, `x3` must be the smallest of all elements of after removing `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, and `y2`.

This gives you a nice recursive algorithm:

```
def generate(n):
    def internal(prefix, items):
        if not items:
            yield prefix
        else:
            for index in range(1, len(items)):
                x = items[0]
                y = items[index]
                # The list of all pairs we've seen so far
                new_prefix = [*prefix, [x, y]]
                # Remove the 0-th and i-th elements from items
                new_items = items[1:index] + items[index + 1:]
                yield from internal(new_prefix, new_items)

    items = list(range(1, 2 * n + 1))
    return list(internal([], items))
```

Comment: Nice. OEIS has some information on these structures. See https://oeis.org/A025035 for the case when each subset is of size 3.